# Java: Updating a GUI element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcomponent

I have to create a game for my final Java school assignment. In it I'm populating a `JPanel` with custom made "Peg" objects that extend `JComponent` in a for loop. The `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout`. Inside the for loop I add the "Peg" objects to an `ArrayList`, and then get the element from that `ArrayList` and add it to the `JPanel`. This is all done in a method that looks like this:

```
public void createDummyPegs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        initPegsArray.add(new ArrayList<>());
        dummyPegsConstraints.gridy = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            dummyPegsConstraints.gridx = j;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                tempColorPeg = new ColorPeg(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                initPegsArray.get(i).add(j, tempColorPeg);
                pegsLeftPanel.add((JComponent) initPegsArray.get(i).get(j),
                                   dummyPegsConstraints);
            }
            else
            {
                tempDummyPeg = new DummyPeg();
                initPegsArray.get(i).add(j, tempDummyPeg);
                pegsLeftPanel.add((JComponent) initPegsArray.get(i).get(j), 
                                   dummyPegsConstraints); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, and it generates a grid of these "Peg" objects nicely. Here's the problem: I have a button that ideally is supposed to replace one of these "Peg" objects with another "Peg" object of a different color. When I click on the button I:

- Create new "Peg" object with the new different color;
- Remove an element from the `ArrayList`, let's the first one;
- Add the new "Peg" to the position where the old "Peg" used to be (assuming of course that it will ultimately reside where the old "Peg" used to be and everything else would be shifted to the right by 1.

Alternatively, I've tried using the `set()` method to just update the element in the given position with the new "Peg". The thing is that when I add the new "Peg" element, it seems that it is not initialized with a size. Sending this new "Peg" to a `System.out.println()` statement to read what's inside of it, it prints out:

```
com.rburgos.mastermindtestlayout.ColorPeg[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

I don't understand why the first time I add to the `ArrayList` it works, but the second time it doesn't.

Any tips of guidance will be greatly appreciated. Here's the full code if that helps:

- [Main program](http://pastebin.com/vList1kb)
- [DummyPeg.java](http://pastebin.com/9AccC8H0)
- [ColorPeg.java](http://pastebin.com/uAXmwKWP)

Comment: The `ArrayList` does not update the components on the screen, there is no connection between them.  When updating the `ArrayList` you will also have to remove the old peg from the screen and replace it with the new one

Comment: Oh, yes, I know that. I'm actually saving the component into an ArrayList and then adding the element from the ArrayList to the JPanel. If you look at the code above `pegsLeftPanel.add((JComponent) initPegsArray.get(i).get(j), dummyPegsConstraints);` does that.

Comment: What about when you replace it?  Replacing the component won't use the existing components constraints.

Comment: Also, a components size won't be updated until the parent container is updated and laid out again

Comment: Cool, thanks for the comment. I think it may have helped me solve the problem, but I need to keep testing to be totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

I feel silly, but I think I was able to figure it out. After adding a new "Peg" to the array and passing that to the JPanel, I was calling `update()`. By calling `revalidate()` now the new "Peg" gets added to the panel. Hopefully this will help others with a similar problem.